# USN Journal leaks information on exFAT-hosted files (in VeraCrypt containers)

Tags: windows, veracrypt, ntfs

I'm using a secondary drive to store encrypted files, in VeraCrypt file containers.
Unfortunately, even if the external drive is formatted as `exFAT`, Windows leaks information on files inside mounted VeraCrypt containers.

[image]

The highlighted file has been created inside the external drive-hosted container.
Thus, how can I prevent this without entirely turning off the USN Journaling (if it's even possible...)?

Comment: The USN Journal isn't leaking anything about the file on the encrypted drive.  What you are seeing is evidence of a shortcut file that existed on your NTFS volume.  If the information in that shortcut is sensitive, you have far bigger problems than the journal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has many default functions that are aimed at common use and support but can become problematic in a privacy/security context.

Not only your example in *Journaling*, but many other functions may be a concern as well. For example, external drive connections, such as *Thumb Drives*, often save drive identities and top level directory filenames in *shellbags* encoded into the registry. This content can persist long after the device is removed.

Once encrypted volumes are unlocked and mounted, all the standard Windows functions apply, including malware scanning, *with copy/export if unknown executable*, of the contents.

Simply plugging a thumb drive into a Windows machine will result in a hidden directory with a GUID (*Globally Unique IDentifier*) being written to the drive. To be fair, Mac's do this as well.

Along related privacy/security lines, encrypted PKzip files maintain a clear text list of all of the filenames in the archive. *Note that 7zip does not do this.*

In short, if you feel you need a higher level of privacy/security, you may want to re-evaluate your choice of operating systems or read [Documentation >> System Encryption](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/System%20Encryption.html).